# How do I access an MVC function via a cron job?

Tags: scripting, codeigniter, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm using CodeIgniter (a PHP framework) to build an app, and I have an every-minute job to run with the program, 24 hours a day. I currently have it set up as:

```
example.com/controller/runthis
```

and that executes the job I want, but cron doesn't visit the URL as a user, it executes a script as far as I know. Do I just write a script that calls that URL/function wuth cURL? My concern is that I'm adding more complexity this way than I'm avoiding by using the framework. Does anyone have suggestions for a case like this? And is there an obvious solution I've overlooked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just load it with wget or lynx.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the script is not doing anything requiring the web server, you could use php-cli to run it from a bash script.

Comment: example? would be very help ful